# bitcoin-qt does not add blocks anymore

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization

I am trying to catch up/synchronize the blocks in my blockchain with `bitcoin-qt`. However, the *last block time* is stuck for hours at `Feb 15 04:29:18 2017` since I started bitcoin-qt the last time.

[image]

What is the reason?

The `debug.log` doesn't show anything supsicios.

When I start bitcoin-qt with `-testnet`, it does catch up.

**Appendix**, as per *Pieter Wuille's* comment, the output of `getchaintips` is

```
[
  {
    "height": 473710,
    "hash": "0000000000000000007eaaf0899877f5317cd2a480477bde88d9e0a9b57a93c8",
    "branchlen": 20592,
    "status": "headers-only"
  }, 
  {
    "height": 473064,
    "hash": "00000000000000000006cdfe729e4aa498a0c03f1e9810fb002e7a36a780f4d1",
    "branchlen": 19946,
    "status": "headers-only"
  }, 
  {
    "height": 472975,
    "hash": "00000000000000000067a24962827bc94d347066a2acec324625da67a0b10168",
    "branchlen": 19857,
    "status": "headers-only"
  }, 
  {
    "height": 453118,
    "hash": "000000000000000000e1823cc186c494caaced15c7761844010362e8bd280bd3",
    "branchlen": 0,
    "status": "active"
  }, 
  {
    "height": 229636,
    "hash": "00000000000000c42b95e4714032ca09b245830b8299d8cf5dda46f75c3755ff",
    "branchlen": 1,
    "status": "valid-fork"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the `getchaintips` RPC? This will not reveal any private information, just a list of which chain forks your node knows about.

Comment: @PieterWuille I've added the `getchaintips` output.